# Make it so Visual Studio Codes show the types of the parameters

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

So I am doing a module for Node.js and I want to have code recommendations, and for it to specify the types of the parameters like this: ([ws module on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws))

[image: example]

it says the variable name and the type. How can I make this with my project?

Comment: They're probably extending the built-in `EventEmitter` class, so VSCode knows the `.on` method already. If you have other functions and classes, [release TypeScript typings](https://betterstack.dev/blog/publishing-type-definitions-with-npm-package/) along with the package.

Comment: @cbr thanks! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: Great! Let me add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The example you've given is giving the types since the class you're inspecting probably extends the built-in `EventEmitter` class, for which VSCode has the types.

To create custom types that VSCode can understand, you could [release TypeScript typings](https://betterstack.dev/blog/publishing-type-definitions-with-npm-package/) along with the package. VSCode [uses TS typings for type acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_typings-and-automatic-type-acquisition).